# POST method not working ReactJs, NodeJs, ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, express, post

**Error**->
[POST method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvNqw.png)

**Above post method not working but similar get method version is working**

I have the following code:
**App.js**

- comm with backend

```
handleData = async (url) => {
    const newData = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id_: this.state.id,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        }),
    }).then(res => res.json());

    console.log('newData-', newData);
    return newData;
}
```

- form

```
<form action='/mainApp' method='POST' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="signUpForm">
```

**sever.js**

```
app.post('/mainApp/show', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Show called');
    const result = await dbOperation.showVals(req.body.name);
    res.send(result.rows);
});

app.post('/mainApp/insert', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Insert called');
    const result = await dbOperation.showVals('email', req.body.email);
    console.log(result.rows.length);
    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        console.warn('Duplicate email address');
        res.send({ errorPresent: true, errorMessage: 'Duplicate email address' });
    } else {
        console.log('Inserting', req.body.id_, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.email, req.body.password);
        await dbOperation.insertVals(req.body.id_, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.email, req.body.password);
        res.send({ errorPresent: false, errorMessage: 'No error' });
    }
});
```

---

***I tried converting all to GET and it was working***

Answer (score 0):

It's working for get method because, you are sending a GET req

```
<form action='/mainApp' method='GET' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="signUpForm">
```

For POST req you have to change the method inside form to

```
<form action='/mainApp' method='POST' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="signUpForm">
```

Comment: The question has a typo
I pasted the GET version for form code

Even with POST method in form tag it is not working